# Manually computed AIC differs from statsmodel AIC

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, statistics, statsmodels

I tried to manually code a formula for the AIC. I want to use it in connection with scikit learn. For testing if i coded correctly, I compared the AIC values from statsmodels given the same datasets. But if i compare model M1 and model M2, my implementation and statsmodels yield differing results; not just numerically, but statsmodels AIC favors another model than my AIC.

I use the manually implemented residual sum of squares and put it in the AIC formula. ols is scikit's ordinary least squares estimator. The index n runs over datasets, y_run(n) is the n_th datasets with response variables, X_run(n) the n-th input training data set. The last piece of code is statsmodel's AIC where regr is statsmodels ordinary least squares estimator.

```py
def rss(n):
    return ((y_run(n)-ols(n).predict(X_run(n)))**2).sum()

def AIC (n):
    return len(X_run(n))*np.log(rss(n)/len(X_run(n)))+2*p

def AIC_regr (n):
    return regr(n).aic
```

Can you see, where my manual implementation is flawed?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I have tried all the combinations using jut n or n-p and so on but no luck. My manually computed AIC is always different (by a lot) from the statsmodels aic. Any new ideia?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is just a difference in definitions.

statsmodels uses the loglikelihood in the definition of aic and not `rss`. `statsmodels.tools.eval_measures` has both definitions.

Information criteria are often only used to compare for different versions, specifically different number of explanatory variables, of the same model. In that case terms that are constant across versions of the model are often dropped. However, statsmodels uses the full loglikelihood definition in the computation of the information criteria. This allows also the comparison across models.

A second issue for the definition of aic is whether it is divided by the number of observations or not. This also varies across statistical packages.

Comment: Thank you Josef. I know, that statsmodel uses the loglikelihood and I use the rss. But the up to a constant, the results should be equal. My problem is, that the order doesn't hold. Let's say M1 and M2 are my models (same type of model but containing different numbers of explanatory variables). statsmodel's AIC yields AIC(M1)<AIC(M2) and my implementation AIC(M2)<AIC(M1).

Comment: What's your `p`? Did you include the constant? I don't see any difference to the statsmodels llf, aic computation. Did you check that you use the same residuals as the statsmodels ols result?